# Getting error: 'Update Failed... DUPLICATES_DETECTED' even with duplicate rule set to 'Allow'

Tags: update, duplicate-management

I am trying to update a list of Contacts which is failing because of duplicate being detected. My duplicate rule field 'Action on Edit' and 'Action on Create' is set to Allow.

code:

```
        if(confirmedMatchesUpdates.size() > 0) {
            //Duplicate rules 'alert' on attempted insert of a duplicate
            try {
                update confirmedMatchesUpdates;
            }
            catch (DMLException e) {
                System.debug('retry!');
                update confirmedMatchesUpdates;
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you want to allow duplicate records to be created or edited then remove the rule in Duplicate Management and it will work.

Comment: @SantanuBoral I require the duplicate rule to be active and to also be able to update Contacts, even if duplicates are found in Contacts. Since the duplicate rule `Action on Edit` field is set to `Allow`, shouldn't it allow the update?

Comment: The rule only runs on edited records when the edited fields are included in the associated matching rule. So what is your matching rule?

Comment: Yes, the rule runs and it sees there is a match based on the fields. I want that to happen, I want my code to see that duplicates are there but update the contacts anyway.

Comment: did you select anything on "Operations on Edit" section?

Comment: yes, Alert @SantanuBoral

Comment: Your last question helped me arrive at a possible solution. I unchecked 'Alert' for "Operations on Edit" and my code now works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The duplicate rule only runs on edited records when the edited fields are included in the associated matching rule.

If you don't select checkboxes for `alert` and `report` in Operations for Create and Operations for Edit section, then system will allow to create duplicate records.